# How to use 'go get' or 'go mod vendor' for a specific module, without trying to update other modules?

Tags: go, go-modules, govendor, go-get

I'm trying to get a specific package from github for a project.

However, when I use `go get [url]` or `go mod vendor`, I get a git fetch error for lack of permissions to one of my company's repos. This repo is vendored, which is how we get around it for go test, go build etc.

This is the error message:

```
go: private.work.repo.com/project/repo@v0.0.0-20190703160253-9c6eb80851f1: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in C:\Users\NICHOLAS.TAN\go\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\37594aeb10b98234e04b4780cf59f32c4ad7bb9da460f552103ae748cea73aa1: exit status 128:
        fatal: remote error: Repository not found
        The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to
        access it.
```

Is there a way for me to use `go get` and/or `go mod vendor` without those commands trying to look at the other module dependencies?

Comment: cant you use `go get <package name>` for packages you need?

Comment: What's your go version? Could you paste the result of `go env`?

Comment: Using `GOPRIVATE=*.corp.com go get [url]` would exclude `*.corp.com` from go modules proxy which is a common reason for fetch problems from private repos.

Comment: @whitespace

I will update question to be more clear, but issue is that if my project has a dependent module 'A' that requires access to a private repo, when I try to 'go get B', I will get an error about not being able to access repo A.

Comment: @hyz my go version is 1.14.6, [here is my go env (with a little bit edited for work reasons)](https://pastebin.com/RGf6mhXP)

Comment: @DmitryVerhoturov I tried this but still seem to get the same error, weirdly enough. Not sure if I am using it wrong, this is the repo URL: ```git.companyname.com/project/....```

and I am using command ```go get [url] GOPRIVATE=*companyname.com```

Comment: I think it should be the other way around: ENV variable then the command. `GOPRIVATE=*.companyname.com go get [url] ` or `export GOPRIVATE=*.companyname.com` once before doing go get.

Answer (score 5):

You can get specific version of package use `go get <package>@<version>` in your project directory, for example:

```
% go get github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.4.0 

go: downloading github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.0
```

Go download only `get github.com/golang/protobuf` package required version to local cache (`$GOPATH/pkg/mod`) and set version to `go.mod` file.

After all, if you have dependencies from your company's repos in local cache (`$GOPATH/pkg/mod`), use `go mod vendor` to create `vendor` (Go get ones from cache).

Comment: Thank you, however the issue isn't that I can't get a specific version, but that it tries to fetch dependencies that are already there while trying to ```go get``` a new one, which is causing problems because I don't have access to all of those dependencies.

Comment: I tried this one (get a specific version) without access to my company's private repo  it works (private repo dependencies was located in my local cache)

Comment: @ozma - Do you use modules or  old approach?

Comment: @ozma Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Sankar Sorry, I can't recall clearly any more, but I think I just temporarily manually removed those files from the go.mod/go.sum, ran the commands, and then added them back.

Comment: can something similar be done if you want to get a specific branch from a repo?  using your example, what if there was a `dev` branch of protobuf, how would you go along trying to get that specific branch, possibly for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issues will occur while getting private module and please check below configuration already done in your local system

Update git global config url

```
 git config --global --add url."git@github.com:".insteadOf "https://github.com/"
```

Update go env to access private go module

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/abc/*
```

Then run installation command